# dynamic sidebar not showing anything

Tags: php, widgets, sidebar

I made custom sidebar and put YITH WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter widget inside to show filter by color. I did the following steps:

1. In my functions.php I registered sidebar like this:

   ```
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_register_sidebars' );
       function my_register_sidebars() {
       /* Register the 'primary' sidebar. */
       register_sidebar(
           array(
               'id'            => 'primary',
               'name'          => __( 'Primary Sidebar' ),
               'description'   => __( 'A short description of the sidebar.' ),
               'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
               'after_widget'  => '</div>',
               'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
               'after_title'   => '</h3>',
           )
       );

   }
   ```
2. I made sidebar-primary.php like this:

   ```
   <div id="sidebar-primary" class="sidebar">
   <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary'); ?></div>
   ```
3. Added widget to my sidebar
4. On my page where I need the content of sidebar to show, I included sidebar-primary.php like this:

   `<?php include('sidebar-primary.php'); ?>`

But nothing is showing. Any suggestions? Maybe I am doing something wrong without even realizing it. Thanx.

Comment: Try to call your sidebar like this `<?php get_sidebar('primary'); ?>` instead of this `<?php include('sidebar-primary.php'); ?>`. See if that works.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I tried, it doesn't work. I tried also with   <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary' ); ?> but nothing shows. I am going out of my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your functions.php file try register sidebar without putting in function like this

```
register_sidebar(array(    //try not to enclose this in function
'id'            => 'primary',
        'name'          => 'Primary Sidebar',
        'description'   => 'A short description of the sidebar.',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
));
```

And make call on page like this

```
<?php get_sidebar('primary'); ?>
```

And in your `sidebar-primary.php` I am assuming you have closed the div. In your code you haven't show closed div of this file.

**UPDATE**

Try the above method and change the `ID name` of sidebar from functions.php You can't use same name for ID and sidebar php file (sidebar_primary.php).

So you need to change Id name from functions.php file and as well as from `sidebar_primary.php`. like

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'primary'); ?></div>
```

In above code `primary` is id and you need to rename it.

Comment: yes, I closed the div, i edited the code here now. I tried your solution, but it still doesn't show anything.

Comment: Thats strange! This is how I use to make my sidebars and it always worked well. Then may be problem is not the code, its something else. Try to disable your all plugins then try to add any default widget in sidebar and see it that works.

Comment: Found solution! see the updated answer